# How to resolve cvs error: no such system user

Tags: version-control, cvs

I am trying to setup CVS on one our server ( let's call it `JEDI`).  Then there is production server called `DVADER`.
I am able to log in from `DVADER` to `JEDI` using  `cvs login` command with production user `STWAR`.   However, as soon as I do  `cvs status`  I get following error :

`Fatal error, aborting.
dsicnspr: no such system user`

I have setup .passwd in CVSROOT folder for production user `STWAR` account on DVADER as shown below.

`STWAR:hsfwfewiiu34de`

However, there is no account of `STWAR` **which is our production id** on `JEDI` which is CVS server.  So there is no entry of `STWAR` in /etc/passwd file on `JEDI`.  I also tried using `SystemAuth=no` in config file inside CVSROOT but that is not working.

`JEDI` the CVS Server is also used for development and have other user account e.g. `LIA` who are able to login to `JEDI`.

Can anyone please tell me how to get rid of this error ?  Do I need to setup account for `STWAR` 
on `JEDI` and make an entry in `/etc/passwd` file ?

Comment: The first thing you should do is change that password and never use it for anything again, since you've just published it (or what I presume is a weak hash of it) on a public forum.

Comment: Thank you. Password and Server names are fake.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.jdknight.me/2015/03/how-to-setup-cvs-server-pserver-on.html

```
sudo chown -R :cvs /opt/cvsroot
sudo chmod -R g+ws /opt/cvsroot

(if you have selinux enforcing)
semanage fcontext -a -t cvs_data_t '/opt/cvsroot(/.*)?'
restorecon -R -v /opt/cvsroot
```

For example:

```
[root@*** ~]# ls -l /usr/local/repo/CVSROOT/passwd*
```

`**-rw-rwSr--**. 1 root cvs   23 Nov 30 10:51 /usr/local/repo/CVSROOT/passwd` -> no error

`**-rw-r--r--**. 1 root cvs 1033 Dec 10 13:59 /usr/local/repo/CVSROOT/passwd.backup` -> error as your questions above!